# unable to run hive from shell action in oozie,can anyone help me one this

Tags: shell, hive, oozie

here is my workflow and error logs respectively.
shell file content:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo
echo
echo "testing"
echo

export HIVE_CONF_DIR=
echo "hive job got started"
cd /opt/mapr/hive/hive-2.1/bin
echo /cygdrive/c/Projects/JLR/embedded_software/main_unit/arm
hive -e "use ozzie_test; create table if not exists test_edh1(name string, id int);"
result=0
if [  -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Hive error number is: "
  exit 1
else
  echo "hive job got completed successfully"
fi
```

error message:

```
getting the errorcode  as 127 
Hive error number is: 127

./testScript.sh: line 11: cd: /opt/mapr/hive/hive-2.1/bin: No such file or directory
./testScript.sh: line 13: **hive: command not found**
```

Comment: What kind of Hadoop cluster is that?!? You are assuming Hive client is installed on **all** cluster nodes (since the Oozie job will run on any node at random), although it's not the way it's done in the MapR preconisations. You are assuming a fixed version of Hive, which will break on the next upgrade. Then you are logging to a local file (on a random node, again). And that local file assumes a CygWin path on a Windows host (yuck!)

Comment: Oozie has a `hive` action, using Oozie shared libs on HDFS, that does not assume Hive is installed everywhere. That's the way to go. Don't try to re-invent the wheel (especially since you clearly can't do it), and read some tutorials e.g. the _"Hooked on Hadoop"_ series.

Comment: Thank you Samson it got ran after copy the Hive conf's to Local .

Answer (score 0):

Is this '**/opt/mapr/hive/hive-2.1/bin**' an hdfs path? If yes, you are trying to use 'cd' command on hdfs path whereas shell checks for that path in local directory and hence the error.

Comment: FYI that's a _local_ install directory for Hive client and/or server components on a MapR cluster node.